# How do I know what is my special mouse button doing and how do I change it?

Tags: mouse, mouse-click

I have a mouse, Havit model ms1020. It comes with two customizable buttons, but the proprietary software to change them does not work. It already comes with two preprogrammed functions, one of them is a back button for webpages and the other one changes which screen is focused.

There are differences between the screen focus button and just left clicking the screen. For example, full screen programs that minimize if you left click another window won't do it if I use this focus button. I tried many keyboard testers and none of them recognized what is this function. Searching for what it is returns some results, but I can't be sure if this mouse is using any of them or some other one.

What could I do to see exactly what is this button doing? Also, is there a way to reprogram it, without the broken proprietary software?

Comment: Try a third-party utility such as X-Mouse Button Control, https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm to see if it can identify the buttons and use the for specific tasks (e.g., scroll one page). Check any downloaded app in VirusTotal before installing, though.

Comment: Thanks, the program works for the remapping, but there is still no way to "log" what the button is doing.